# Missing Weeks View

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2

I have 2 tables which I need to compare to find missing data.

TableA: Definition table

```
Year, Week, cmp_code, [other columns]
```

TableB: Cash Receipts

```
Year, WeekNo, FranchiseID
```

TableA has all the possible combinations of ID week and year we *should have* data for. TableB is the data we actually have. I need to list out what we don't have yet, so the delta for B-A. How do I construct the query to find these missing values?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [NOT EXISTS](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms188336.aspx)

```
SELECT  [Year], [Week], ID 
FROM    TableA AS a
WHERE   NOT EXISTS
        (   SELECT  1
            FROM    TableB AS b
            WHERE   b.[Year] = a.[Year]
            AND     b.[Week] = a.[Week]
            AND     b.ID = a.ID
        );
```

Comment: I later found that I need to include more columns from TableA than TableB has. This answer ultimately fit my needs better, though both would work.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the`except`set operator to return the difference between two sets:

```
SELECT [Year], [Week], cmp_code FROM TableA
EXCEPT
SELECT [Year], [WeekNo], FranchiseID FROM TableB
```

This will return the rows in TableA that doesn't have exact matches in TableB. The same result can be achieved using a correlated`not exists`query, or a`left join`. The`not exists`should perform best.

Comment: I edited the OP for accuracy in column names. Does it matter what the names are? Does this 1to1 match?

Comment: No, the names does not matter, the only thing that matters is that the columns in each position are comparable either directly or through implicit conversion. The number of columns must be the same though.

Comment: Ah ok. I ended up needing more columns from A than I'm comparing with B. Thank you for your help!